# How do you add values in sequence in output in R?

Tags: r

Say I have the following block of code:

```
function2x <- function(x){
  x * 2
}

results <- c()

for (i in seq(1, 10, by = 1)){
  function2x(i)
  results <- c(results, function2x(i))
}

results
```

It would spit out `[1] 2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20`

How do I go turning this into a table which shows the corresponding `i` value?

So it would show this:

```
i results
1  2
2  4
3  6
4  8
5  10
6  12
7  14
8  16
9  18
10 20
```

Comment: No need for loop `function2x(1:10)`

Comment: Your output is a `vector`.  You can just convert to a `matrix` with `matrix(results)` would be a one - column output or `data.frame(i = seq_along(results), col1 = results)`

Answer (score 1):

Just `cbind` a `seq`uence.

```
x <- (1:10)*2

cbind(id=seq(x), x)
#       id  x
#  [1,]  1  2
#  [2,]  2  4
#  [3,]  3  6
#  [4,]  4  8
#  [5,]  5 10
#  [6,]  6 12
#  [7,]  7 14
#  [8,]  8 16
#  [9,]  9 18
# [10,] 10 20
```

Answer (score 1):

The OP's output is a `vector` and it can be converted to a `data.frame`

```
data.frame(i = seq_along(results), results = results)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `function2x` is vectorized so you can avoid the `for` loop and do

```
data.frame(results = function2x(seq(1, 10)))

#   results
#1        2
#2        4
#3        6
#4        8
#5       10
#6       12
#7       14
#8       16
#9       18
#10      20
```